# How to add asp.net identity in asp.net core with visual studio code

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, visual-studio-code

This is my first project in asp.net core and now have come to the point where I need to implement asp.net identity for core mvc application in visual studio code.

I looked up but neither I can find any blog and any document on Microsoft sites how to do it. If anyone can help me out, it will be great and sure many other will get answer to this.

Thanks,
Girish

Comment: Please follow this tutorial here https://www.tutorialspoint.com/asp.net_core/asp.net_core_identity_configuration.htm

Comment: thanks for your reply, I tried this tutorial but it's out of date I think. Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework is no longer supported in asp.net core 1.1, I am getting incompatible message and haven't been able to find right package as an alternative for core.

Comment: @TAHA I followed the linked tutorial and got the same error. The [solution](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/3439) I found was also outdated (for VisualStudio 2017), but fixed with a [migration guide](http://www.natemcmaster.com/blog/2017/01/19/project-json-to-csproj/): Open your .csproj file in a text editor and add `;net45` to the following line: `<PackageTargetFallback>$(PackageTargetFallback);portable-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81;net45</PackageTargetFallback>`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can create new project using `dotnet new mvc --auth Individual` command and then copy identity-related code to your project.

Comment: This seems promising, I will try this and update you. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: doesn't have a way to add it to an existing project?

Comment: @Campinho not possible using the IDE according to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45696743/1068167

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the following command

```
dotnet add package Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework --version 2.2.3
```

Note that this package will install the dependency packages: EntityFramework and Microsoft ASP.NET Identity Core.

Reference: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework/