# Visual Studio for Mac - Windows Authentication - Is it feasible?

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, windows-authentication, visual-studio-mac

I'm operating in a mixed environment with some developers using macOS and others Windows 10.  I've got an ASP.NET Core 2.0 MVC project that is configured for Windows Authentication and can be tested/debugged in Visual Studio on Windows but I'm clueless how to enable Windows Authentication while testing the app in Visual Studio on the Mac.  Is this even feasible?

Comment: Hi, Stack Overflow is for programming issues only ..

Comment: So programming tools aren't considered "programming"?  Color me confused.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is from CLI. Please try this command from terminal-

```
dotnet new mvc -o moviemvc --auth Individual
```

reference : [visual studio mac for mac missing of identity class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45694583/visual-studio-mac-for-mac-missing-of-identity-class/45696743#45696743)